# backbone.js error as TypeError: this.on is not a function this.on("change:src", function(){

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have been going thru this book "developing backbone.js application"
where on page 18 theres a model function which goes like this:

```
    (function($){
    var Photo = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            'src': 'placeholder.jpg',
            'title':'an image placeholder',
            'coordinates':[0,0]
            },
        initialize:function(){
            this.on("change:sr", function(){
                var src = this.get("src");
                console.log("Image src has been updated to: "+src);
                });
            },
        changeSrc: function(source){
            this.set({'src':source});
            }
        });
    var somePhoto = new Photo({'src':'test.jpg', 'title':'testing'});
    somPhoto.changeSrc('thatPhoto.jpg');
    })(jQuery);
```

Its give me an error as

```
TypeError: this.on is not a function
this.on("change:src", function(){
```

on console.
Any Idea how i may solve this problem. I'm entirely new to Backbone.js.
Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: oh.. yes it seems that way.. i was using old version of backbone. bind instead on works just fine.. thank you so much fencliff.

Comment: I moved my comment as an answer, so the question doesn't remain unanswered forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be using an old version of Backbone. `on`/`off` were only added on 0.9.0, before that they were called `bind` and `unbind`.

You should update to the latest [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) (0.9.9 at the time of writing).

Comment: +1 Most beginner tutorials were written in 2010/early 2011 when bind was being used!